# count certain words on html file by python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a rookie in Python. I am trying to count some words or expressions on html files. For example,I have a piece of html with source codes as below:

```
<div style="line-height:120%;text-align:justify;text-indent:24px;font-size:10.5pt;">
<font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:10.5pt;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;">2013 vs. 2012&#160;&#160;</font>
<font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:10.5pt;">During 2013, the Company recognized a decommissioning charge of $117 million and a restoration liability of $50 million, partially offset by the 2013 reversal of the $56&#160;million tax indemnification liability associated with the 2006 sale of the Company&#8217;s Canadian subsidiary.</font></div>
```

I want to count how many times "liability" show up in the piece. Below is my  code, which is not working:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

lst=os.listdir("C:/html/")
for x in lst:
    print (x)
    html = open ("C:/html/"+x,'rb')
    bsobj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    metricslist = bsobj.findAll(div.string ='liability')
    print(len(metricslist))
```

I know bsobj.findAll(div.string ='liability') is very wrong, but have no idea on what the code should be. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you only looking for text that appears in a `<div>`, or can it appear anywhere?

Comment: It can appear anywhere in block-level, such as <p>..but the text I am looking for is not within any other tags, such as <span>....</span>. If you check the source code of my html, you will see "liability" is not within any other tags, except in<div> ...  </div>

Comment: Use a xpath expression to find all useful elements like `div` and `p`. Then, for each element, extract the text (it can also be with a xpath expression like `string(.)`). Then, with the RegEx `\bliability\b`, use `re.findall` to find all occurrences in the text. Then count the occurrences.

Comment: @Laurent Thanks for the suggestion. This surely is one way to reach my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a *partial string match* on an element's text when using `find()` or `find_all()`:

```
soup.find(text=lambda text: text and "liability" in text)
```

Or, a [regular expression pattern](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) can be used in place of a [function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
soup.find(text=re.compile(r"\bliability\b")
```

Comment: alecxe, thanks a lot for your help! You solution is great, it works easily and neatly.